# Morris chart appends new data from ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, morris.js

I have been working on a project and i have to show some order details in a morris chart. The data of chart is in JSON format and is taken as a response from a servlet.

There is an apply button and a to from datepicker, when i press the apply button, JavaScript function parse the data from servlet. It is working correctly. I have placed the chart div in my webpage and i am only loading my JSON data in it.

When I press apply for the first time, the data is loaded and shown in the chart using **setData()** function provided by morris. As below:

[image: JSON data from external API]

But when I press the apply button for the second time, it appends data to the current chart as below:
[image: Appended data]

The javascript function for making this possible is as follows:

```
function parselineData(method,url,id,no,keyx,keyy)
{   var datefrom=document.getElementById("from"+no).value;
    var dateto=document.getElementById("to"+no).value;
    if(datefrom=="")
    {   document.getElementById("lfrom"+no).style.color="red";
        document.getElementById("lfrom"+no).innerHTML="*From:";
    }
    else
    {   document.getElementById("lfrom"+no).style.color="black";
        document.getElementById("lfrom"+no).innerHTML="From:";
    }
    if(dateto=="")
    {   document.getElementById("lto"+no).style.color="red";
        document.getElementById("lto"+no).innerHTML="*To:";
    }
    else
    {   document.getElementById("lto"+no).style.color="black";
        document.getElementById("lto"+no).innerHTML="To:";
    }
    if(datefrom==""||dateto=="")
    {
    }
    else
    {   var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        var chart=Morris.Line
        ({  element: id,
            data:[{date:"0",orders:"0"}],
            xkey: keyx,
            ykeys: [keyy],
            labels: [keyy],
            smooth: true,
            resize: false
        });
        var data;
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4&&xmlhttp.status==200)
            {   data=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                //alert("My Data is" + data.toSource());
                chart.setData(data);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open(method,url+"?from"+no+"="+datefrom+"&to"+no+"="+dateto, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

Please help so that I could show data without appending it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when the chart's container already contains a chart and you call `setData` which inserts a another new chart along side the first one.

You should clear the container before calling `setData`. Something like:

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "";
chart.setData(data);
```

Comment: I am getting an unresponsive script error on rapheal.min.js with this

Comment: id is id of a div tag.

Comment: Are there any JS errors that you can see? Assuming that `id` looks like `some-name` then there shouldn't be any problems here, unless you're using elements inside of `some-name` for something else?

Comment: <div id="some-name">
</div>
This is how my div is.

Comment: What's in the variable `id`?

Comment: some-name,
It is working fine without,
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "";

Comment: function call,
<input type="button" value="Apply" onclick="parselineData('get','APIName','some-name','1','date','orders')"/>

Comment: In your console, what do you get if you enter `document.getElementById('some-name')`?

Comment: I am getting that div, 
<div id="some-name" style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"> and more

Comment: my problem is solved, i add document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=""; in if condition of ajax function, but now it is solved when i am using it out of it.